# Macro fail with E488: Trailing characters: i:

Tags: macro

I have something like this :

```
neckbeard: "https://appa.com/emoji/neckbeard/c8ec7bf188.png",
metal: "https://appa.com/emoji/metal/9f936a4278.png",
fu: "https://appa.com/emoji/fu/2f615de37f.png",
feelsgood: "https://appa.com/emoji/feelsgood/7bcbaa15fa.png",
finnadie: "https://appa.com/emoji/finnadie/08e66eb46d.png",
goberserk: "https://appa.com/emoji/goberserk/d8b892d59b.png",
godmode: "https://appa.com/emoji/godmode/1bd6476fbb.png",
hurtrealbad: "https://appa.com/emoji/hurtrealbad/b9c3d648e6.png",
rage1: "https://appa.com/emoji/rage1/0c3685290c.png",
rage2: "https://appa.com/emoji/rage2/feaf8897c6.png",
```

And I want this

```
:neckbeard:
:metal:
:fu:
:feelsgood:
:finnadie:
:goberserk:
:godmode:
:hurtrealbad:
:rage1:
:rage2:
```

I tried a macro `@ai:<esc>f"D0` did a visual select to all the line and then `:'<,'> @a` but I get `E488: Trailing characters: i:`. I've tried with a default vimrc without plugins.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to user [normal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3anormal)

So it's `:'<,'> norm @a`

And it's work